# Do any Veda take about expanding universe?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, rig-veda, science

Does Rig Veda or any Veda say about expanding the universe?

Comment: https://youtu.be/T-eRqTdCpZY watch this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigveda 2:15:2 translated by Dharmadeva Vidyamartandeya.

[image]

The word बृहन्तमा is used in this verse which means expanding or growing.